# Cocoapod podspec to reference iOS and OSX projects

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods, podspec

Are there any examples or suggestions on how to make a CocoaPod podspec that is used by both an iOS project **and** OSX project within a workspace? I'm working on a pod that uses bluetooth and I'm sure many will want both their OSX project and iOS project living in the same workspace referencing the same Pod.

There are several things I'm unsure about, such as changing the Base SDK between iOS and OSX, and how to make the project reference either an iOS or OSX target.

Anyways, any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are plenty of projects that do both in the specs repo.

Comment: Thanks for writing Keith. I did not see any examples that helped too much. For example, I can pod install AFNetworking for an OSX project. But then, in that workspace, the confusion starts if I have another project / target for iOS which might need to do similar networking. So, I could go into the Pods project and duplicate the Pods-AFNetworking target, change the SDK to ios, along with any path info that might need to change, ... - but I'm sure there's a better way. Anyways, if you have any thoughts, please let me know.

Comment: You're going to want to specify the target the specs link with for this. Then you can have separate groups for your OS X and iOS targets.

Comment: Thanks Keith. With your suggestions, I think I got it. I documented my findings here, https://github.com/PunchThrough/Bean-iOS-OSX-SDK/wiki , under 'Extras'.  Anyways, thanks again!

Comment: Yep it looks good to me!

Comment: @MatthewChung you can answer your own question and mark the answer as correct to help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Keith. The correct answer is in the comments above. To see a sample go to github.com/PunchThrough/Bean-iOS-OSX-SDK/wiki

Comment: This is a link only answer. Please describe how.